# when i click cancel in confirm dialog password changed how can i stop change password in javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, servlets

In my application I did change password page in that when I enter passwords and click button it raises  successful message in that when i click cancel button it also password changes how can i stop changing password by clicking cancel button

```
        var udet = ['ChangePassword',$('#txtNewPassword').val(),$('#txtOldPwd').val()]              
         $.ajax({               
              type: "Post",
              url: "UserRegistration",   //Servlet page here have code for checks current passowrd                  
              dataType:'json',
              data:{json:udet},
              success: function(data)
              {
                  if(data=="Password Changed Successfully"){
                  confirmDialog($("#message").html("<span style=color:black;>"+data+"</span>"), function(){               
                    $(window.location).attr('href', "Home.jsp");    

                  });                
                  }
                  else{
                  $("#message").html(data);
                     $('#txtOldPwd').val('');
                    $('#txtNewPassword').val('');
                    $('#txtCnfirmPwd').val('');
                 }
              }
              });
```

Comment: assuming #confirmCancel is the dialog you mean, just put it as first line in yoursuccesshandler. sorry, question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: Sry, @Dominik, I changed my question could you please tell me

Comment: a bit more code is required where you are opening the prompt for cance or change

Comment: as manikant says, where do u call your code above? Please show us your full definitions of the click-handlers for submit / cancel-button. Without it, we're not able to help. It's most likely you've accidentally set the same handling for cancelbutton than you did for submit, but this is just a guess.